# Separate header div on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

What I am trying to do is have my header on site http://horizonworks.lddesigns.co.uk stay at the top of the page but when the user scrolls to a certain point in the page, another header appears and sticks to the top of the screen.

I've seen it done on this site http://leighton.com and wondered how it was done!

Comment: Check the scroll offset and display a `div` with `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

**[1]**

```
window.setInterval(function()
{
    if(window.scrollTop == 40)
    {
        document.getElementById('yourHeader').style.top = window.scrollTop.toString() + 'px';
    }
}, 500);
```

*or*

**[2]**

```
var update = window.setInterval(function()
{
    if(window.scrollTop == 40)
    {
        document.getElementById('yourHeader').style.position = 'fixed';
        clearInterval(update);
    }
}, 500);
```

Change **40** to the number of pixels down the user has to scroll to 'make it happen'.  I would use **#2** to preserve memory.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you just need to check your window scrolltop position on scroll of the window and then compare it with the position of the target div position.

I have done a POC: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/5Ft4j/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header">Default Header</div>
<div class="content1">Content 1</div>
<div class="content2">Content 2</div>
<div class="header2">Another Header</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.header{background:#F00; height:100px}
.content1{background:#00C; height:600px}
.content2{background:#0C0; height:600px}
.header2{background:#666; height:100px; position:fixed; top:-100px; width:100%}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $(window).bind("scroll", function(){
        var winPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
            divPos = $(".content2").offset().top, // If you want you can set a fix value here also
            newPos = winPos >= divPos ? 0 : -100;

         $(".header2").stop().animate({
             top : newPos
         });
    });
});
```

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the [Waypoints jQuery plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) with the "sticky" add-on. Just follow the instructions. Something like:

`$('.header').waypoints('sticky')`

Using `sticky`, you have to add your own CSS to a class called "stuck." Something like:

`.stuck{
position:fixed;
top:-60px;
}`

Comment: Thanks for this, I am just in the middle of making it work, I want it to fade in when scrolled to a certain point and then fade out when scrolled up past that same point if that makes sense.